# Let's precede V with a byte of zeroes: 0x00 || V

Tags: терминология, битовые-операции

В англоязычном тексте встретил такое:

> Let's precede V with a byte of zeroes: 0x00 || V

Подскажите, как это максимально точно перевести на русский, чтобы текст соответстовал коду (0x00 || V)?

Первый байт в V сделаем нулевым? Первый байт в V заменим на нулевой? Или еще как-то иначе?

Comment: А что вообще происходит при операции 0x00 || V ? Это замена первого байта или добавление (приклеивание) к V спереди нулевого байта??

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

> Let's precede V with a byte of zeroes: 0x00 || V

Я бы дословно перевел как:

> "Пусть V предшествует байт из нулей"

Или

> "Пусть байт из нулей предшествует V"

Так будет звучать более ясно, чем первый вариант.

Можно также добавить к слову байт следующие выражения

> "Пусть байт, состоящий из нулей, предшествует V"

или

> "Пусть байт, содержащий нули, предшествует V"

В программировании можно также сказать "нулевой байт":

> "Пусть нулевой байт предшествует V"

хотя "нулевой байт" - не совсем однозначное выражение. В разных контекстах это выражение может пониматься по-разному.

Кроме того так как используется Let's а не просто Let, то можно также перевести как

> Давайте предположим, что байт из нулей предшествует V.

или

> Предположим, что байт из нулей предшествует V.

Что использовать, предыдущий перевод или этот, зависит от дальнейшего контекста.

Comment: `Добавим перед V байт из нулей: 0x00 || V`
будет более точным переводом.